# What kind of approach should I apply for face validation with using deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, multiclass-classification, image-recognition

My research task is face recognition in cars with using deep learning method. Actually, in example we set an driver randomly and then the question is: Is this person driver or not?

So i created an custom dataset that includes 47 different persons's faces when they are driving cars. Every person's have 3000 face images and I used [MTCNN](https://github.com/ipazc/mtcnn) for detect faces from images.

But I'm confused; is the problem multi-class classification or binary? I mean the result is binary (driver or not) but we'll set driver after created this model. for that I can not divide the dataset like driver and others.

When I researched I found that one-class classification approach. [Deep One-Class Classification](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v80/ruff18a.html) Is this help me or not, I don't get it.

What I should do?

Comment: "I mean the result is binary (driver or not) but we'll set driver after created this model".  Can you explain a bit more?  Is your dataset all examples of "driver" with no examples of "not driver"?

Comment: Actually yes, all persons in the dataset can be set as driver. For example let say person_5 is driver so all the other persons are could not driver. When we gave an image except from person_5, it must say "not driver".

Comment: Oh I see now!  I believe this problem would best be described as "image similarity detection".  Given a reference image (e.g. person_5), the model needs to determine if future images match or not

Comment: @zachdj Oh it related to Siamese Neural Network I guess. I'll be looking at. Thank you!

Comment: check out this work on facial recognition https://github.com/wesleylp/CPE775